# error in xaml when converting bytes to image in wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Ihave created a convertor in in wpf which gets bytes array and I want to return an image. The returned image is binded into the image control in xaml. but in xaml this error is happening:-
NotSupportedException: **No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.**

My converter is in vb.net:-

```
Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert

 If value Is Nothing Then Return Binding.DoNothing
        Return ToBitmapImage(value)
 End Function

 Private Function ToBitmapImage(ByVal bytes As Byte()) As BitmapSource

        Dim bitmapImage As BitmapImage = New BitmapImage()

        Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(bytes)
            ms.Position = 0
            bitmapImage.BeginInit()
            bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = ms
            bitmapImage.EndInit()
        End Using

        Return bitmapImage
    End Function
```

in XAML--
  Any guideline where I am wrong? I have tested ToBitmapImage() function in a and it's OK.

Comment: I've tried this converter and not found any problem...

Comment: during bind I am using that code in xaml:-   <Image Source="{Binding Path=TestImage, Converter={StaticResource imgConverter}}" 
           Stretch="UniformToFill" StretchDirection="Both">
                <Image.BitmapEffect>
                    <DropShadowBitmapEffect Color="Black" />
                </Image.BitmapEffect>
            </Image> I am getting the component not found exception

Comment: TestImage is the byte array property. imgConverter resource is already added in xaml as   <local:BinaryImageConverter  x:Key="imgConverter"/>. Can't understand where is the issue in xaml?

Comment: Can only think that your Byte array has some problem. I get a Byte Array by reading an image file. This error occurs when setting the value for BitmapImage.StreamSource. There maybe a problem with `bytes` argument. Try remove `ByVal`?.